# What's wrong with a colon: in a ###comment?

Tags: .htaccess

When I added

> deny from 82.118.       ### 82.118.242.240 (country: BG)

to .htaccess, subsequent attempts to visit my site resulted in a 500 server error.

Simply changing the colon **:** to a dash **-**

> deny from 82.118.       ### 82.118.242.240 (country- BG)

now works fine.

But I'm not googling any problem with colons in comments.
So I tried just changing a comment line from

> ### added automatically...

to

> ### added: automatically...

just adding an extraneous colon after "added". And that causes no problems at all. So what's going on, and what's the general rule that my "deny from" with colon is violating?

Comment: Comments should always go on their own line in .htaccess for recent versions of Apache

Comment: @JustinR. Thanks. I split the offending comment off to a separate line, and re-changed the dash back to the original colon (just in case that particular comment syntax was especially offensive to the parser for some reason). And like you said, now there's no problem with the colon in a comment on its own separate line.

Comment: Glad it helped.  As it answered your question, I'll submit it as the correct answer.  Much appreciated if you'd mark it correct / upvote.

Comment: @JustinR. done, and thanks again. But I feel extremely safe and confident guaranteeing you that these stackexchange points count for absolutely nothing. (I checked my Oxford English Dictionary http://www.oed.com/ and under "meaningless" it says "See stackexchange reputation points.")

Comment: The points don't really count for anything, but they do seem to sometimes have an effect on how some people on here will handle your questions and answers.  It's akin to "likes" on social media.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache's configuration format doesn't support inline comments.  Comments should always go on their own line in `.htaccess`.  Putting a comment after conditions/rules will cause them to be treated like a parameter.